# A question on lie groups( Lie algebras)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, foliations

What is an example of  a compact Lie group $G$ which is not isomorphic to a product of two nontrivial lie groups  and satisfies the following property:

There are two  non zero vector fields $X, Y \in g$, the lie algebra of $G$, such that the corresponding one dimensional foliations $F_{X}$ and $F_{Y}$ are not topological equivalent?

Comment: Such a Lie group $G$ is always isomorphic to $G\times\{e\}$, its product with the trivial group. Perhaps there are some refinements to be made to the question.

Comment: Yes. The simplest example: take a torus $T:={\mathbb R}^2/{\mathbb Z}^2$ and a couple of tangent vectors at $0$. One can provide the foliation with compact leafs, the other may have all leafs dense.

Comment: @Sasha torous does not satisfies the condition in my question. it is product of $S^{1}$ by $S^{1}$

Comment: Ok. So, you may try to take a product and quotient it by a finite normal subgroup so that the result is no more a product, but those compact and noncompact leafs survive. (Of course, the torus does not work anymore.)

Comment: @SashaAnan'in Are you talking about quotient of 2- torous by its finite subgroup? in this case what is the resulting lie group(after quotient). Note that every compact commutative lie group is  a torous. Could you please explain more precisely?

Comment: Take Sasha's example, and embed it into the simple Lie group $SU(3)$ (where $\mathbb{T}^2$ embeds as a maximal torus).

Comment: @Alain @ Ali Yes. Many compact groups which are not products contain a compact one-parameter subgroup as well as non-compact one. The cosets with respect to those provide desired foliations.

Comment: @AlainValette Prof.Valette, thank you very much for$SU(3)$ example. I have a related question; What is a pure (Lie) algebraic interpretation for the following property of a finite dim. lie algebra $L$: For every lie group $G$ with $Li(G)\sim L$ and for every two non zero $X,Y \in L$, two foliations $F_{X}$ and $F_{Y}$ are topological equivalent, as two foliation on $G$. Are such lie algebras, classified?